# Run file with default program and wait until end of edit

Tags: java, file, wait

I want to open file dowloaded from server with default program and wait until edit is completed (to upload changed file on server). I made this in such way:

```
public void init() {
    try {
        int fileId = Integer.valueOf(this.getParameter("id"));
        System.out.println("Downloading");
        String filePath = downloadFile(fileId);
        String[] cmd = { "cmd.exe", "/C", "start /wait " + filePath };
        System.out.println("Opening");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Uploading");
        uploadFile(filePath, fileId, address, session);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is working preety good except the case if file extension is not associated with any program. Windows display dialog for chooseing program and after client make a choice process is ended and file is immediately upload on server. Have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Isn't it easier to let the user to decide when he want to upload the file back? I mean show him a button "Upload it back" or anything similar.

Comment: Such functionality is already implemented, but I need an edit button which behave exacly as I describe above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that if there is no associated application with the extension, a seperate process is spawned to ask the user what application to use. There is unfortunately, not much you can do from Java, unless you know exactly what application to call, you won't be able to monitor the file editor if it's not associated with the file prior to launch.

This is an OS feature and there's no easy way around it.  Depending on the file type, you might want to "guess" what application the user will use and call that directly instead of the command interpreter, but that is very risky and error prone.

Comment: If I see correclty, it is a Windows-only application, as cmd.exe is exists only on Windows OS.

The main problem is the open application is maybe cannot edit the given file, e.g. images' default open application is the Windows Image Preview (or what is the name), not the MSPaint.

Comment: This is not the main problem. I can accept that default program actually doesn't edit a file.